# how to setup local DNS service in office?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

i want to use the the domain name example.local instead of 192.168.1.100 in the local context.
in the mean while, the user will still be able to access the Internet.

anyone can help to suggest what are the steps i need to do?
things like:
which dns server should i choose? 
how to configure it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform, Windows or Linux? If Windows, I believe you need Server; if Linux then "bind" is the program to install and search for help on.

Comment: @pjc50, BIND can also be installed on Windows, thereby eliminating the requirement for a Server OS.

Answer (score 0):

Use your local [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) for resolving this domain name.

Comment: Without a hosted dns server, this needs to be setup on each client.

Comment: The use of hosts creates a maintenance nightmare that causes far more problems than it solves. It should be used on individual machines for special purposes only, never as a substitute for DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .local as your domain as it will conflict with Zeroconf/Bonjour.

If you have a Linux server in the mix, I would look at `dnsmasq`.  You can configure it to do DHCP, in which case I would disable DHCP on the router.